# ASP.NET_SessionId cookie value is alway Lax in the SameSite

Tags: asp.net, samesite

I have an ASP.NET Web Application and the application need to open in an iframe in another site i.e. it should support cross-site cookies. I want to set **SameSite=None; Secure** in the web application. I put

```
<httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
```

in the Web.config but the **SameSite** value in the cookie **ASP.NET_SessionId** is always **Lax**. Am I doing the right configuration in web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<httpCookies sameSite="...">` attribute in Web.config doesn't affect the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie. Set the `<sessionState cookieSameSite="...">` attribute instead:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Even I changed to  <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
and my site is running in https, the cookie is always in SameSite=Lax. What could be the reason?

Comment: (1) Are you sure you're updating the correct Web.config? Try setting cookieSameSite to an invalid value like "ABC" and making sure it produces an error. (2) Make sure you've cleared all cookies in the browser so that a new session cookie is issued. Existing cookies will retain the original SameSite value even with this change.

Comment: After clearing all existing cookies from the browser, it worked fine. Is it also needed to set <httpCookies requireSSL="true"/> for SameSite="None"?

Comment: Yes, you need to set `<httpCookies requireSSL="true">` so that the Secure attribute is added to the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie. (There is no separate attribute on `<sessionState>` like there is for `cookieSameSite`.)

Answer (score 0):

After writing the below code in **Global.asax**, I am able to bring **SameSite** value to **None**.

```
        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            //while we're at it lets also make it secure
            if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
                Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Secure = true;
        }
```

An alternate way to achieve this is in the web.config file.

```
<system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>
        <sessionState cookieSameSite="None"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to address the cookies of the **Response** object in **Session_Start** ? 
Each time a *new* session starts ... Cookie NOT YET not available.

You can use

```
Request.Cookies[ASP.Net_SessionId"]
```

instead.  I addressed the Request object and problem solved.